# Advantages writing CSS as JS object vs normal CSS?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Since v3.3.0 [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) has first-class object support:

```
const Button = styled.button({
  color: 'blue'
})
```

What advantages are there to write it like above compared to the "standard" CSS way with template literals:

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: blue;
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any advantages or disadvantages, other than those implied by the difference in syntax.

[This thread](https://spectrum.chat/thread/2b5fd935-fb1d-480d-a524-95ecd540a1ac) and [the documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#style-objects) both imply that it's simply a matter of syntax preference:

From the docs:

> styled-components optionally supports writing CSS as JavaScript objects instead of strings. This is particularly useful when you have existing style objects and want to gradually move to styled-components.

From the thread:

> We just released styled-components v3.3.0 with first-class object support! (finally) Lots of people have been asking for this for a while, here's what it looks like:
>       const Button = styled.button({
>         color: 'blue'
>       })
>   Note that this fully optional, we ❤️ template literals and writing actual CSS—this is just an option for folks who prefer to write their CSS as objects.